# How to remove all but the checked item from a CursorLoader?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have an activity that displays a listview of doctor's for a user to select. Each listview item contains a checkbox and a doctor's name. My end goal is that when the user checks a doctor, all others are removed and only the selected doctor remains.

In the adapter class, I have the following code snippet:

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
});
```

I have code that stores the previous cursor so it can be restored if a doctor is unchecked, but I have removed that to simplify this question. Currently, when I check the checkbox nothing happens. I have tried adding `notifyDataSetChanged()` but the adapter has no registered observers so that made no difference. How can I let the activity know that an item has been selected?

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) I know I should register a `DataSetObserver` but I don't know which object should be registered and how.

**EDIT**

Here is some more from my Adapter class:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags){
    super(context, cursor, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME));
    String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME));
    String suffix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_SUFFIX));

    viewHolder.nameView.setText(firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + suffix);

    // Should I add something here?
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public final CheckBox checkBox;
    public final TextView nameView;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseDoctorCheckBox);
        nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseDoctorLabel);
    }
}
```

The adapter is used in an activity that implements a CursorLoader to load the data into a listview. In the activity, I am able to call `doctorAdapter.swapCursor(someCursorIWant);` but I can't reference the  selected doctor. Something I have tried:

```
// Set currentDoctor (a property of the adapter class) if a new one is checked.
// Again, other checks removed for simplicity.
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            currentDoctor = cursor;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

And then in the activity:

```
// Set observers
mDoctorAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        Cursor c = mDoctorAdapter.getCheckedDoctor();
        if(c != null)
           mDoctorAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: Are you using CursorLoader?

Comment: Yes, in the activity I have several lines that call `doctorAdapter.swapCursor(someCursor)` but if I try to call it within the adapter class itself it won't work. I can't move this code to the activity, because I can't figure out how to reference the checkbox listener from the activity.

Comment: Register it to your adapter. I've never used android adapters, but in the API documentation I see a `registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver)` method. Couldn't you use that? Not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly

Comment: What flags are you using in CursorAdapter constructor?

Comment: The flags are 0, and @VinceEmigh what should I register? I don't have any `DataSetObserver` objects in the activity, and I can't find any that I can cast to that type.

Comment: You'd create a new one, wouldn't you? [DataSetObserver Example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.database.DataSetObserver). Although, like I said, I've never used a CursorAdapter (not an android dev; rarely use the android api), so I'm only saying this based off your assumpsion of needing it

Comment: Nothing,  dont register anything,  CursorLoader does it,  all you need is just to update your ContentProvider, see CursorLoader.loadInBackground() sources

Comment: @pskink I'm still not sure, if the activity implements CursorLoader but the Adapter class has reference to the checkbox, how do I know which cursor to load? I will take a look at some examples and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: You should use only one Cursor: the one that comes from the latest CursorLoder

Comment: You have to fetch the cursor again for the selected doctor and call swapCursor(yourSelectedDoctorCursor), I think then it should work.

Comment: @Krish I have access to the selected doctor inside the `onCheckedChanged` method, and that's what I'm trying to call `swapCursor()` with, but it's not updating the view.

Comment: Can you post the code for adapter?

Comment: How would swapping the cursor with _itself_ achieve anything? If you want to limit your adapter to a subset of the result set, then you will have to write some custom logic for that.

Comment: @corsair992 it wouldn't achieve anything, and that's not what I'm doing. I'm trying to swap the cursor of the adapter itself with the one that is passed into the `bindView` method that represents the current doctor.

Comment: @McAdam331: They're both the same object - `bindView()` is just a convenience method that receives it at the relevant index as a parameter.

Comment: @corsair992 Even still, in the edited part of my example I'm not doing that. I'm assigning a variable to the current object being selected, and retrieving that variable form the activity. So, in the `onChanged()` method, the cursor for the doctor adapter should be swapped with the cursor representing the doctor who was checked, but it's not doing anything.

Comment: @McAdam331: As far as I can see, that's exactly what you're doing. The `cursor` that you're storing is the same that's passed to `bindView()`, correct? And that's the same object that's already set in the `CursorAdapter`. I suggest you do some research into how `Cursor` and `CursorAdapter` are implemented, as it doesn't look like you have a clear idea on it.

Comment: @corsair992 perhaps not. I've been working on this issue for a few days now. I came to Stack Overflow because I couldn't find the solution else where. I thought that's what this site was for, but it doesn't look like I have a clear idea on it. When I figure it out, I will try to post the answer.

Comment: @McAdam331: Basically, if you're using `CursorAdapter`'s main functionality, you'll need to acquire a new `Cursor` with the result set that you need by requerying the database. I suggest you take a look at the various filtering related APIs in `CursorAdapter`. I'm sure people will post plenty of answers as you have offered a bounty, but do your own research and take them with a grain of salt.

Comment: @corsair992 I understand. I have used filters before, I have an EditText that allows the user to type text and it will filter the listview to pull for rows that contain the input text. I just can't wrap my head around this one. I will try to see if I can set a filter when the item is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. What I did was adjust the `bindView()` method to store the id of a doctor when it is selected:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry._ID));
    String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME));
    String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME));
    String suffix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_SUFFIX));

    viewHolder.nameView.setText(firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + suffix);

    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                selectedDoctorId = id;
            } else{
                selectedDoctorId = 0;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, I registered a new observer in the activity, and in the `onChanged()` method I pull the id and use a new Uri to query for just that doctor:

```
// Add observer for doctor
mDoctorAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        if(!systemEntered && mDoctorAdapter.getSelectedDoctorId() != 0){
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    DoctorEntry.buildDoctorUri(mDoctorAdapter.getSelectedDoctorId()),
                    DOCTOR_COLUMNS,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
            systemEntered = true;
            mDoctorAdapter.swapCursor(c);
            systemEntered = false;
        }
    }
});
```

I had to use a boolean flag called `systemEntered` to prevent an infinite loop. Without it, calling `swapCursor()` sets off `onChanged()` again, and I requery, and so on and so forth. Now, when I check the checkbox of a specific doctor, all others are removed from the list. Thanks to all who took their time to look into this.

---

**EDIT**

Based on suggestions from the comments, I have changed this to use callbacks instead. In my adapter class, I included the following interface and method:

```
private DoctorAdapterCallbacks mCallbacks;

viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked && mCallbacks != null){
            mCallbacks.onDoctorChecked(id);
        }
    }
});

public void onRegisterCallbacks(Activity activity){
    mCallbacks = (DoctorAdapterCallbacks) activity;
}

public static interface DoctorAdapterCallbacks{
    void onDoctorChecked(long id);
}
```

And in my activity (which implements the interface) I have added the following code:

```
// Set callbacks (This is in the onCreate method)
mDoctorAdapter.onRegisterCallbacks(this);

@Override
public void onDoctorChecked(long id) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(SELECTED_DOCTOR_ID, id);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(SELECTED_DOCTOR_LOADER, args, this);
}
```

I have created another CursorLoader that is intended to handle only a single doctor, and that loader will replace the previous one (of all doctors). Thanks again for all the help and suggestions.

Comment: You should use a `CursorLoader` to query the row that you need, instead of performing the query on the main thread - that is the whole point of using a `CursorLoader` after all. It would also be better to use some other way to notify the `Activity` to requery, instead of using a dummy dataset change notification and observer.

Comment: @corsair992 I suppose I could create a new Loader (or find a way to manipulate my existing doctor loader) but I can't find any other way to notify the Activity.

Comment: You can just set a custom listener callback interface, and register it from the `Activity`. Or, if you want to do it in a hackier but easier way, you can probably just cast the `Context` to your `Activity` subclass, and call any custom method on it.

Comment: @corsair992 similar to the relationship between an activity and a Navigation Drawer's callbacks?

Comment: Yes. Or like the `OnClickListener` (or `OnCheckedChangeListener`) interface on `View`. You just define an interface with a callback method, provide a method for registering it in the adapter class, implement and register the callback from the `Activity`, and notify the registered listener of the relevant events

Comment: @corsair992 thanks for your advice, I really appreciate it. I have implemented some callbacks instead.

Comment: I suggest changing the parameter type to the listener interface instead of defining it as `Activity` and then casting it. There is no need to limit the implementation to a subclass of `Activity` (it may be a `Fragment`, or it may use another internal object as a listener), and you also lose compile-time type checking that way.

Comment: I think this is already suggested in my second solution, actually I do not mention `callback`, because it is just a function to call restart loader.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to remove the checked items from the cursor, but you can't do that directly, so you need `ContentResolver#delete()` calls or `SQL`

EDIT:

You can't delete just from cursor. You need to re-query filtered results, so that after you change the checked state, you also change a flag

Comment: That will remove it from the database too, not just the cursor.

Comment: And *removing* the checked items is the opposite of what I want to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it in two ways:

1)using [FilterQueryProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html)
You set a `filterQueryProvider` with a query value that if it runs it will select the specified doctor. When a doctor is checked you set the `filterQueryProvider` to the adapter with a `constraint value` for example equal of `doctor id`. in `runQuery` of `filterQueryProvider`you must return a cursor which select a doctor who has a `constraint id`. then every time a doctor is checked you simply call `adapter.getFilter().filter(doctoreId)`

you should also override `changeCursor` so it dose not close the previous cursor **(the one that returns by the loader)** because closing the cursor is the responsibility of the loader.
So in your case check the cursor size and if it is equal to one close it but if it is not, do not close it.

2)Adding a new uri to your content provider that is used to return just a doctor by his id. then when the user checks a new doctor you call a new initLoader with a loader id and the required information  bundle to select the doctor.

Comment: I've already used a `FilterQueryProvider` on the adapter to allow the user to filter doctors by typing in a textview. Is it possible to add a second one? Also - I have a Uri already to query for a doctor by specific id, I just don't know how to call it when the checkbox is selected.

Comment: For the first part, I think you can create a class that extends `FilterQueryProvider` which accepts different parameter `(constraint)` and one of them is doctoreId so if the doctor is checked you simply call `adapter.getFilter().filter(doctoreId)` and because inside of the `runQuery` of that class you will receive the `doctoreId` you can get the correct doctor too(filtered the list using new cursor).

Comment: For the second part you can simply run `restartLoader` with a docterId as a bundle that is passed to the function. then in onCreateLoader you will check the bundle and if it has the doctorId you will use the URI of selecting one doctor.